# Spark 2.0.2 SparkSQL - simple join condition on first char of strinig doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to join two tables based on the first character of a column, in PySpark:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table1 A CROSS JOIN table2 B WHERE A.last_name[0]=B.last_name[0]")
```

ERROR = Can't extract value from last_name#16

Thank you for your time and guidnace.  Peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets are `array` notation, not string splicing. Use `substring` function:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A JOIN table2 B
WHERE substring(A.last_name, 0, 1) = substring(B.last_name, 0, 1)
```

Example:

```
spark.sql("SELECT substring('foo', 0, 1)").show
+--------------------+
|substring(foo, 0, 1)|
+--------------------+
|                   f|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A CROSS JOIN table2 B 
    WHERE substring(A.last_name, 0, 1)=substring(B.last_name, 0, 1)
```

Thank you.